# Is the following statement true about probabilities and their complements?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw the following statement written, but I can't understand why it is true.

$$
\dfrac {P(A \text{ and } B)}{P(B)} = \dfrac{P(A)-P(A \text{ and }B^c)}{ 1-P(B^c)}
$$

Any help understanding why these are equivalent would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: look at the basic laws of probability. What is the relation between $P(B^c)$ and $P(B)$? How  is the set $AandB$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the denominators $P(B)$ and $1-P(B^c)$ are equal because $P(B)+P(B^c)=1$ (either $B$ happens or it doesn't).

For the numerator, $P(A\text{ and }B)$ is the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen.  For $P(A)-P(A\text{ and }B)$, consider $P(A)$ first.  $P(A)$ is the probability that $A$ happens.  When $A$ happens, either $B$ happens or $B$ doesn't happen.  This means that $P(A)=P(A\text{ and }B)+P(A\text{ and }B^c)$.  By rearranging, you can see the numerators are the same.

Comment: Thanks so much. This makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ and $B^c$ satisfy $B \wedge B^c = \emptyset$ and $B \vee B^c = \Omega$, we have$$
P(A \wedge B) + P(A \wedge B^c) = P(A \wedge \Omega) = P(A).
$$
As a consequence, $$\tag{1}P(A \wedge B) = P(A) - P(A \wedge B^c).$$

In addition, the special case $A = \Omega$ gives
$$
\tag{2}P(B) = 1 - P(B^c).
$$
Finally, $\dfrac{(1)}{(2)}$ yields what you want.